# Dell laptop shuts down instead of rebooting

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I have a Dell Inspiron I7-7797 running Ubuntu 20.04.
When I run **sudo reboot** from the terminal the laptop shuts down instead of rebooting.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: This issue started when I changed the video driver from X.Org X server -- Noueav display driver to NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440. I went back to the X.Org X server driver and the laptop reboots normally.

Comment: I actually have some notes from dealing with this myself. The notes are install `laptop-mode-tools` and adding `acpi=noirq` to GRUB.